# Too quick votes to close?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, vote-to-close

I've experienced that, as a newbie programmer, I need answers to many 'newbish' things. In many events I need help with stuff like "is it bad practise to use this function (example)", and it'll quickly get closed as subjective and argumentative.

Does anyone else realize that this is a problem?

Comment: An argumentative question is mostly about *how* you ask. Can you give an example?

Comment: Here's all your [closed questions on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A542308+closed%3A1). Which question are you referring to? The only "subjective and argumentative one" is [What is the best online, free JavaScript tutorial?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4527488/what-is-the-best-online-free-javascript-tutorial-closed)

Comment: @Greg: There are the PHP vs C#/.NET ones too.

Comment: Good point. I may have *ahem* an ignored tag in there. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry but all your closed questions look like they were closed for good reason to me.  It seems you need to read the [faq](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) about what types of questions to ask and try using the search feature before posting.  Reposting your own question multiple times is also frowned on.

StackOverflow has enough traffic that if you're asking noob questions, it's almost certainly been covered before.  If after looking at the close reason given on the question and reading the faq you're still not sure why it was closed, let us know which question it is that you're wondering about.